# Preprocess data for prediction in Google Cloud (Cloud Functions doesnt support Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I use `Google Cloud Functions` to send data for prediction to the `Cloud ML Engine`.

Firstly, I need to preprocess the data before sending it to the `Cloud ML Engine`.

For preprocessing I use 2 tokenizers (*mwetokenizer* from `nltk` and *tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer* from `tensorflow`).

When I load tokenizers into `Google Cloud Functions`, I get an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_preprocessing'

This is due to the fact that `nltk` and `tensorflow` do not support Python 3.7.

**Question**: What can I do to preprocess the data and send it to the `Cloud ML Engine` for online prediction?

Comment: FYI, [Tensorflow now supports Python 3.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517#issuecomment-461910761)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with Cloud Functions until those libraries support Python 3.7. You'll need to use a different service that provides a Python 3.6 runtime, such as the [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/) (which provides Python 3.6.4).

---

**EDIT:** [TensorFlow now supports Python 3.7.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517#issuecomment-461910761)